# Error:Execution failed for task ':sampleAppProject:dexDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, libraries

I just updated my sdk tp version 23 so as my libraries in my application but when it comes to run the app the following error is presented :com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2,
I checked the meaning of it it says possible duplication of libraries like android module v4 and v7 within my app and libraries the post said to exclude these libraries to prevent duplication but I'm not achieving that here is my app gradle hope anyone can help me achieving this thanks.

```
enter code here
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  android {

signingConfigs {
    XXXX_release {
        keyAlias 'XXXX'
        keyPassword '123456'
        storeFile file('XXX')
        storePassword '123456'
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'
lintOptions
        {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            //abortOnError true
        }
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'XXXXXX'
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 4
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes
        {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles './proguard-rules.pro'
                //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'

            }
        }
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
    incremental true
}
configurations {
   //all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support',module: 'support-v4'
   // all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support',module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
productFlavors {
}

}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
compile files('Libraries/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
compile project('Libraries:UniversalImageLoader')
compile project('Libraries:facebook')
compile files('Libraries/gcm.jar')
compile files('Libraries/quickblox-android-sdk-chat-2.0.jar')
compile files('Libraries/quickblox-android-sdk-core-2.0.jar')
compile files('Libraries/quickblox-android-sdk-messages-2.0.jar')
compile files('Libraries/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.6'
compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.6'
 }
```

Comment: Did you try restarting the android studio? Also, there must be something else too in the error log apart from what you have mentioned.

Comment: @PrerakSola restarting didnt solve the issue but i cant achieve what was told in this post http://www.dahuatu.com/V6mMREjwbq.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it turns out:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
```

which is causing the over 65k methods, so removed it, gradle sync, cleaned project, and then ran again and then this error stopped. I needed just maps and gcm and the ads so i put these lines:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.8.0'
```

and synced project and the error is gone no need for the whole play service.
Hope this will help anyone who face this.